# Excluding data using WHERE clause but only on certain conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have the below code which works but I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this or if this method is frowned upon?

I essentially want to return all the data using the first 3 where clauses and then if US Fixed Income with the Strategy containing Global then to hide the Average Price row.

```
SELECT
        [vw_Characteristics].[Classification_Category]
       ,[vw_Characteristics].[Portfolio_Value]
       ,[vw_Characteristics].[Index_Value]
       ,[vw_Characteristics].[Sort_Order_PChars]

FROM    [dbo].[vw_Characteristics]

WHERE   [vw_Characteristics].[ACCOUNT_NUMBER] = @Account
  AND   [vw_Characteristics].[AS_OF_DATE] = @Date
  AND   [vw_Characteristics].[Sort_Order_PChars] IS NOT NULL
  AND   CASE 
            WHEN    @Domicile = 'US'
            AND     @Capability = 'Fixed Income'
            AND     @Strategy LIKE '%Global%'
            AND     [vw_Characteristics].[Classification_Category] = 'Average Price'
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END = 1

ORDER BY [Sort_Order_PChars] ASC

DROP TABLE #elink
```

Comment: Why do you need a `case` there at all? You could just do `and not (a and b and c and d)`.

Comment: Or you could just use `not (...)` !! Also, if you used a table alias and discarded the unecessary [ ] it would make reading it so much easier.

Comment: Oh of course, doh.

Comment: This was flagged for close, but I feel it is an important lesson for the community to learn, there are no silly questions, unless they have been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost never makes sense to use a `CASE` expression in a `WHERE` clause, mainly because the `CASE` is evaluating conditional logic that could have simply been in the `WHERE` clause as native criteria.

The following should be similar to your equery:

```
SELECT
        [vw_Characteristics].[Classification_Category]
       ,[vw_Characteristics].[Portfolio_Value]
       ,[vw_Characteristics].[Index_Value]
       ,[vw_Characteristics].[Sort_Order_PChars]

FROM    [dbo].[vw_Characteristics]

WHERE   [vw_Characteristics].[ACCOUNT_NUMBER] = @Account
  AND   [vw_Characteristics].[AS_OF_DATE] = @Date
  AND   [vw_Characteristics].[Sort_Order_PChars] IS NOT NULL
  AND   NOT (       @Domicile = 'US' 
            AND     @Capability = 'Fixed Income'
            AND     @Strategy LIKE '%Global%'
            AND     [vw_Characteristics].[Classification_Category] = 'Average Price'
            )
ORDER BY [Sort_Order_PChars] ASC
```

The only times that I see `CASE` as a potential is when the case logic changes the fields to filter on, or the order of the criteria, but even then it would have to be very complicated logic to justify such syntax. it wouldn't make the query any more efficient, but it might improve the maintainability of it over the long term.

Comment: Can you cite the documentation for the `case` _statement_? I'm only familiar with the [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_. My apologies if that's a silly question.

Comment: Not a silly question, just a silly mistake on my part, I meant expression